# Refactoring messy if else statement

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, refactoring

I am working on a legacy code base which has the following snippet:

```
if ((results[0].Length == 0))
    customerName = "";
else
    customerName = results[0].Substring(18);

if ((results[1].Length == 0))
    meterSerialNumber = "";
else
    meterSerialNumber = results[1];

if ((results[2].Length == 0))
    customerID = "";
else
    customerID = results[2];

if ((results[3].Length == 0))
    meterCreditAmount = "";
else
    meterCreditAmount = results[3];

if ((results[4].Length == 0))
    debtInstallmentDeduction = "";
else
    debtInstallmentDeduction = results[4];

if ((results[5].Length == 0))
    vatOnEnergyAmount = "";
else
    vatOnEnergyAmount = results[5];

if ((results[6].Length == 0))
    vatOnDebt = "";
else
    vatOnDebt = results[6];

if ((results[7].Length == 0))
    outstandingDebtAmount = "";
else
    outstandingDebtAmount = results[7];

if ((results[8].Length == 0))
    tariffCategory = "";
else
    tariffCategory = results[8];

if ((results[9].Length == 0))
    tariffId = "";
else
    tariffId = results[9];

if ((results[10].Length == 0))
    encryptedToken1 = "";
else
    encryptedToken1 = results[10];

if ((results[11].Length == 0))
    encryptedToken2 = "";
else
    encryptedToken2 = results[11];

if ((results[12].Length == 0))
    encryptedToken3 = "";
else
    encryptedToken3 = results[12];

if ((results[13].Length == 0))
    encryptedToken4 = "";
else
    encryptedToken4 = results[13];

if ((results[14].Length == 0))
    systemMessage = "";
else
    systemMessage = results[14];

if ((results[15].Length == 0))
    customerMessage = "";
else
    customerMessage = results[15];

if ((results[16].Length == 0))
    predefinedMessage = "";
else
    predefinedMessage = results[16];

if ((results[17].Length == 0))
    transactionAcknowledgeNumber = "";
else
    transactionAcknowledgeNumber = results[17];
```

What would be the best way to refactor this for acceptable coding standards? Would it be acceptable to make this a case statement instead?

Comment: Post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com and not on stackoverflow.com

Comment: I am not asking a code review I am asking whether a switch statement to serve this purpose would be considered acceptable coding standards

Comment: It would be more readable. You'd probably use some key in the switch-statement right?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a case-wise execution so it can't be refactored to a switch-case. However it can be converted to functional code and then it factored out into a separate method so that the "ugly" part is hidden behind a method call.

---

### Step#1 - Making the code functional

Here, we rewrite the code by following functional code writing practices. The rewritten code will look like:

```
customerName = (results[0].Length == 0) ? "" : results[0].Substring(18);
meterSerialNumber = (results[1].Length == 0) ? "" : results[1];
customerID = (results[2].Length == 0) ? "" : results[2];
meterCreditAmount = (results[3].Length == 0) ? "" : results[3];
debtInstallmentDeduction = (results[4].Length == 0) ? "" : results[4];
vatOnEnergyAmount = (results[5].Length == 0) ? "" : results[5];
.
.
.
transactionAcknowledgeNumber = (results[17].Length == 0) ? "" : results[17];
```

There are numerous advantages of writing the code this way. Important ones include:

- terseness of code;
- values being initialized at one place (by means of ternary operator) instead of two (one in `if` and another in `else` clause).

---

### Step#2 - Factoring out the method

Now that the values are being initialized functionally, you can create a class (or you may be already having this class) containing the properties `customerName`, `meterSerialNumber`, ..., `transactionAcknowledgeNumber`. Either the constructor of the class can be designed to read the `results` and populate the class members or you may write a method to read the results. So it will look like:

```
ResultValues resultVal = new ResultValues();
resultVal.Read(results);
.
.
.
//Accessing the values later in the code
Print(resultVal.customerName);
...
```

---

---

<sub>*PS:*</sub>

<sup>1. I admit that `ResultValues` may not be a good class to make. Alternatively, you may create multiple classes by clubbing the related data and then have the `Read()` method of those classes read the values from `results`.</sup>

<sup>2. The essential idea of Step#2 is to factor out the "ugly" part to another simple and readable method call(s).</sup>